# network address translation and public IP address

Tags: networking, nat

can one NAT have multiple public IP addreses for same end hosts behind it?

also

can one NAT have multiple public IP addreses one for each end hosts behind it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and yes. NAT potentially represents a complete abstraction between private and public IP addresses; a single private address could make two outgoing connections and use a different public IP for each.

Whether that's useful is questionable, particularly since some protocols assume that a single application will always have the same public-facing IP address. And I don't know why you'd ever do 1:1 NAT. But you could, if you really wanted.